# VirtualBox - how to free up unused VDI disk place?

Tags: virtualbox

So if I have a dynamical storage in virtualbox guest, how can I reduce the VDI's size, if there are many unused place in the guest?

So I mean I know the virtualbox guest in reallity is about ~3 GByte's large, but the VDI file is 10 GByte, because once a while the guest was that big. But it's now only 3 GByte's big. How can I reduce the VDI's size? So that it would be only 3 GByte's big? (and no, there aren't any snapshot's about the guest)

Comment: **Related:** [How to force files together on a Linex partition?](http://superuser.com/questions/170913/how-to-force-files-together-on-a-linux-partition)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at [vboxmanage modifyhd](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvdi): it allows you to make an image more compact.

> With the --compact option, can be used to compact disk images, i.e.
> remove blocks that only contains zeroes. This will shrink a
> dynamically allocated image again; it will reduce the physical size of
> the image without affecting the logical size of the virtual disk.
> Compaction works both for base images and for diff images created as
> part of a snapshot.
>
> For this operation to be effective, it is required that free space in
> the guest system first be zeroed out using a suitable software tool.
> For Windows guests, you can use the [sdelete](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897443) tool provided by
> Microsoft. Execute sdelete -c in the guest to zero the free disk space
> before compressing the virtual disk image. For Linux, use the zerofree
> utility which supports ext2/ext3 filesystems.

Comment: *Use* `sdelete -z` *not -c!* See https://superuser.com/questions/747820/what-is-the-different-between-sdelete-c-and-z -- the -c option just overwrites with random data for a "secure wipe" (slightly wearing SSDs).

Answer (score 8):

Be careful -- MS changed the meaning of "-c" (clean) and "-z" (zero) at some point.  To be safe, run "sdelete /?" to see which option you should use:

```
C:\> sdelete /?

SDelete - Secure Delete v1.6
Copyright (C) 1999-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

usage: sdelete [-p passes] [-s] [-q] <file or directory> ...
       sdelete [-p passes] [-z|-c] [drive letter] ...
   -a         Remove Read-Only attribute
   -c         Clean free space
   -p passes  Specifies number of overwrite passes (default is 1)
   -q         Don't print errors (Quiet)
   -s or -r   Recurse subdirectories
   -z         Zero free space (good for virtual disk optimization)
```

Comment: The -c option overwrites with random data (see https://superuser.com/questions/747820/what-is-the-different-between-sdelete-c-and-z), which slightly wears SSDs. Use -z for zeroing.